# How do I get the DateTime Python module to hold the day of the week without specifying the date?

Tags: python, datetime

```
Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(f"{AnimeListDates[show]['day_of_the_week']}-{AnimeListDates[show]['start_time']}", '%A-%H:%M')
```

if I do Date.weekday() I will get 0(monday) no matter what I put in the day of the week field. After a little bit of testing I found out that the date when not specified defaults to 1970-01-01 which is a 0 (monday). Is there anyway I can make a datetime object hold the day of the week without a date? Working around this would be very tedious and require me to store a date for each day of the week and pass that in whenever it was detected or something along those lines.

Edit: An example of what could be in the strptime "thursday-23:30"

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to use a datetime object to begin with? If you only need the days of the week, why not just use the integers 0-6 ? Sharing what you're trying to accomplish and perhaps showing some more of your code might help.

Comment: Date.weekday() will not always give zero. It will vary based on date. for example `from datetime import datetime; datetime.now().weekday()` is giving 5 for me today

Comment: @sytech I edited the post with an example of what I am putting into strptime. The reason I want to work with datetime is because I want to take the day of the week + the time and subtract 14 hours from it then give me the new day of the week

Comment: @Rahul It always gives a zero if you don't give it a date. I only gave it a day of the week and time. It is defaulting to 1970-01-01 which is a monday so it gives 0

Comment: Cayn you simplify your code to include actual values insted of some dictionary? like `Date = datetime.datetime.strptime('0-10:30')`. I still don't get it how you would normally get a weekday from day of the week. You can add a little explanation

Comment: @Rahul Without the dictionary the input would look like this: "thursday-23:30".
An example of my issue:
`
Date = datetime.datetime.strptime("thursday-23:30", '%A-%H:%M')
print(Date.weekday())
`
This would return monday instead of thursday
I think the reason is because I didn't specify a date so it defaulted to 1970-01-01 which is a monday
`
print(Date)
`
returns 1970-01-01 23:30 for refrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no. Datetime objects are always associated with a specific date and time. You cannot separate weekday from the date.

> I want to take the day of the week + the time and subtract 14 hours from it then give me the new day of the week

Based on your comment on your objective, you can go about solving your problem a different way:

If you want to work with *days* absent of a specific date, then the `calendar` module may be appropriate. Although, you really just need to know the names of the week.

You could use this in conjunction with `datetime.time` objects if you need methods dealing with time, absent of any particular date.

```py
import calendar
days = list(calendar.day_name) 
# ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
my_animu = AnimeListDates[show]

show_time = datetime.time.fromisoformat(my_animu['start_time'])
show_day = my_animu['day_of_the_week']

show_day_index = days.index(show_day.title()) # analog to date.weekday()
```

To get the new day and time 14 hours earlier:

```py
new_hour = (show_time.hour - 14) % 24
new_time = show_time.replace(hour=new_hour)
if 14 > show_time.hour: # 14 hours ago is the previous day
    new_day_index = show_day_index - 1
else: # 14 hours ago is still the same day
    new_day_index = show_day_index
new_day = days[new_day_index]
print(f'{new_day}-{new_time}')
```

Comment: Glad that was helpful @RobbyS -- If this answers your question fully, feel free to mark this answer as accepted :-)

Comment: Thank you this is very useful :) If I am going to manually process the times anyway I might just stray away from datetime and calendar all together.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. parsing the string 'manually' wouldn't be much change in effort. Alternatively, you could try using the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) package to get arbitrary dates on a particular weekday. But it kind of begs the same question of why go through all the trouble when you can do this with a more rudimentary approach like you mentioned.